# Azure Update Management

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am having an issue with my Azure Update Management not pushing the updates to the Windows VM. 
This was working before I domain joined to Azure Active Directory Domain Services.

From what I have read on the Microsoft Site, it looks like this is a known issue, wanted to shoot it off here to see if anyone has found a work around. It looks like that it is not selecting the updates. I do have the selection in the schedule setup to do all updates.

Things I have tried.

- Recreated the Services Account.
- Deleted and redid the automation account
- Delete and setup the Updates Management Configuration
- Verified they do work manually.

I am relatively new to Azure, so I apologies for the lack of knowledge.

Comment: Can you share a link to the Microsoft Site where it shows the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since found the answer. The Worker process from Azure has to be reinstalled if it was installed prior to the domain join.